# Excel Data validation fails on specific cell and corrupts file each time on save

Tags: excel, list, validation

so I have a bit of a hard time phrasing this question, but it stumps me.
I have multiple cells on my worksheet which have data validation lists. There are three distinct lists, two in single cells and one in a range of cells. All of them are populated through a bit of code which pulls a JSON formatted string, puts it into an object, iterates through the key/value pairs and puts the values in the list (all done in VBA).

One of the single cells and the range of cells behave like they should, and maintain the list/dropdown after closing the workbook. The second single cell comes back empty every time, with Excel opening to the following error:

"We found a problem with some content in 'YourWorkbook.xlsb'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"

followed by:

"Repaired Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.bin part".

It then has the one single cell with the data validation dropdown arrow, but no list. To be sure, there are **no** formulas in my entire workbook, so am perplexed by the "formula from sheet2.bin" part.

The only discernible reason I can think of is that this list is longer than the others (but still only 54 entries, 414 characters total).

Does anyone have a good way to circumvent/reason for this happening? I'd prefer not to store the list in a cell.

Code to replicate - just add into an empty workbook, save as .xlsm or .xlsb and re-open.

```
Sub ValidTest()
Dim A, x%, y%, z%

For x = 1 To 3
    For y = 1 To 25
        For z = 1 To 10
            A = A & x + y
        Next z
        A = A & ","
    Next y
Next x

Sheet1.[A1].Validation.Delete
Sheet1.[A1].Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=A
Sheet1.[A1].Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
Sheet1.[A1].Validation.InCellDropdown = True

A = ""

For x = 65 To 75
    For y = 1 To 5
        A = A & Chr(x)
    Next y
    A = A & ","
Next x

Sheet1.[B1].Validation.Delete
Sheet1.[B1].Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=A
Sheet1.[B1].Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
Sheet1.[B1].Validation.InCellDropdown = True

Sheet1.Range("C1:C5").Validation.Delete
Sheet1.Range("C1:C5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=A
Sheet1.Range("C1:C5").Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
Sheet1.Range("C1:C5").Validation.InCellDropdown = True

End Sub
```

ps - this is in Excel 2016, 32bit

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Perhaps if you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you can edit your question to provide information someone can use to help you.

Comment: Try opening the workbook in Excel/safe mode, then launch the VBE and Debug > Compile VBA Project.  Sometimes the error message will return as corrupt if there is an error in one of the codes.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Added some code - it's quite easy to reproduce actually. It seems to have to do with the list being too long.

Comment: @Jenn thanks for checking this, but it's not a code problem.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code using F8? I see for both of your data validation ranges, you are using a list with values between, but only Formula1 is rederenced

Comment: Have you stepped through the code using F8? I see for both of your data validation ranges, you are using a list with values between, but only 

> Formula1

 is referenced. When using 

> xlBetween

, both formulas must be referenced.

Comment: @Jenn - please just run the code, it's not a code issue. I very much appreciate the help, but it has to do with the validation list length it seems. The code runs fine.